# Sort data in array by field value === 0

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have some data structured in the followng way:

```
theArray = [

    0:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 5,
            finished : 7
        }
    ],
    1:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 0,
            finished : 3
        }
    ],
    2:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 3,
            finished : 1
        }
    ],
    3:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 0,
            finished : 7
        }
    ],
    4:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 4,
            finished : 0
        }
    ]

]
```

I would like to rearrange the arrays inside `theArray` by `status.started`, so that any arrays with `status.started === 0` are pushed to the bottom. So `theArray` would look like this:

```
theArray = [

    0:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 5,
            finished : 7
        }
    ],
    1:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 3,
            finished : 1
        }
    ],
    2:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 4,
            finished : 0
        }
    ],
    3:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 0,
            finished : 3
        }
    ],
    4:[
        0 : {},
        1 : {},
        2 : {},
        3 : {},
        status : {
            started : 0,
            finished : 7
        }
    ]
]
```

I'd preferably like to use Underscore.js if possible. It's never let me down in the past!

Comment: This isn't event valid JavaScript...

Comment: @meskobalazs Isn't it?

Comment: `[` or `{` ...........

Comment: @PranavCBalan That's what I meant.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: Arrays must have keys with the same type (number or string). Otherwise, it's an object.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ That's not correct!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a start with underscore.js:
Just for moving the elements with status.started to the bottom.

```
_.sortBy(theArray, function(element) {
    return element.status.started === 0 ? 0 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to sort based on *value === 0 or not*, you can assign default values and compare it.

```js
theArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  var _v1 = a.status.started === 0 ? 1 : -1;
  var _v2 = b.status.started === 0 ? 1 : -1;
  return _v1 < _v2 ? -1 : _v1 > _v2 ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice question but in this case sort is not necessary because we are not sorting anything. It's just the business of moving the black sheep to the end of the line. So why not just splice it out from the where it is and push at the very end. But then the indices shift and your `forEach` loop becomes funny. Ok that's why we have a nice `reduceRight()` for us to play with. You delete the current index position item and shoot it to the end... and yet the next item is still the same next item. Cool. Let's do it.

```js
var theArray = [{ 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 5, finished: 7 } }, { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 0, finished: 3 } }, { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 3, finished: 1 } }, { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 0, finished: 7 } }, { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 4, finished: 0 } }];
theArray.reduceRight((p,c,i,a) => !c.status.started && a.push(a.splice(i,1)[0]));
console.log(theArray);
```

So that's it. Only in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your hash wasn't syntactically correct so I took the liberty of fixing that. After that, you can use.

```
    theArray.sort(function(a,b) {
         return b.status.started - a.status.started;
    })
```

This is the whole code with the fixed input.

```
    theArray = [

        {
            0 : {},
            1 : {},
            2 : {},
            3 : {},
            status : {
                started : 5,
                finished : 7
            }
        },
        {
            0 : {},
            1 : {},
            2 : {},
            3 : {},
            status : {
                started : 0,
                finished : 3
            }
        },
        {
            0 : {},
            1 : {},
            2 : {},
            3 : {},
            status : {
                started : 3,
                finished : 1
            }
        },
        {
            0 : {},
            1 : {},
            2 : {},
            3 : {},
            status : {
                started : 0,
                finished : 7
            }
        },
        {
            0 : {},
            1 : {},
            2 : {},
            3 : {},
            status : {
                started : 4,
                finished : 0
            }
        },
    ]

    theArray.sort(function(a,b) {
         return b.status.started - a.status.started;
    })
    console.log(theArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a default value of `Infinity` for non started items.

```js
var theArray = [{ 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 5, finished: 7 } }, { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 0, finished: 3 } }, { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 3, finished: 1 } }, { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 0, finished: 7 } }, { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, status: { started: 4, finished: 0 } }];

theArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.status.started || Infinity) - (b.status.started || Infinity);
});

console.log(theArray);
```